# How do I remove a Windows upper class filter driver?

Tags: windows, drivers

At some point in the past I tried out a serial monitor program from HHD Software. Somehow it left it's port monitor driver (hhdspmc64.sys) installed on my system. I'm trying to track down problems, and I want this thing gone so I can prove it's not the source of my other problems.

I've proven it's a class filter using the [devcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command (from the Windows DDK): `devcon classfilter Ports upper`, which lists hhdspmc64 as the only upper class filter on that class.

How do I get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a few tries, but I finally found the appropriate invocation of devcon to do the job:

devcon classfilter Ports upper !hhdspmc64

A variety of examples of devcon usage are found at the [examples page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and reading `devcon help classfilter` is mandatory for understanding the removal syntax.

Comment: Is there a different way to do this nowadays? devcon no longer seems to work and pnputil does not appear to be able to remove it. This driver is keeping me from enabling Core Isolation on Windows 11 and it's annoying the hell out of me.

Comment: When you say devcon no longer works, do you mean this invocation? Were you running from an admin shell? Because I'd bet that on modern boxes you have to be admin to have devcon actually work. Also, did you examine the devcon help? It's possible something has changed.

Comment: I couldn't get devcon to run at all, it only gave me an invalid operation message. However, I've managed to remove the driver using pnputil. Pnputil couldn't remove the file though, and the presence of that file in System32\Drivers was keeping me from enabling Core Isolation. After some experimenting, it turns out that now that pnputil had uninstalled the driver, I could just delete the file and core isolation would turn on.

Comment: Thank you! you saved me. This method helped me solve the problem. before that I had the error "Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. To fix this problem you should uninstall and then reinstall the hardware device. (Code 19)" and I could not work with USB devices FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001